# Tastypie Authorization not exactly authorizating?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Lets say that we want to be able to update only those objects of which the stage integer field is lower than 3. (or a similar example, that we want to limit the permission to object update only to the Owner users=fields.foreignkey). So the first example authorization will look like this:

```
class RecordAuthorization(Authorization):
    def update_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        if bundle.obj.stage < 3:
            return True
        raise Unauthorized("You can't update this")
```

or the second example:

```
class RecordAuthorization(Authorization):
    def update_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        if bundle.obj.user == bundle.request.user:
            return True
        raise Unauthorized("You can't update this")
```

Actually neither of them will work (I tested the first one and it does not work).
When you look closely into the tastypie documentation they say:

> object_list is the collection of objects being processed as part of
>   the request.

So this means that in `object_list`, there are the json objects only rewrote to python list of dicts? So there are NOT the real object from database, therefore this filtering:

```
def update_list(self, object_list, bundle):
    return object_list.filter(stage__lt=3)
```

won't work as expected (allowing updates only to objects having stage lower than 3). And will do something like-> if the json (sent through API, not the object in database) stage is lower than 3 allow updated. So actually you can update an object with stage=5 (in database) to stage=1!
I get the same strange results for the update_detail function, too. So I suspect that the bundle.obj is also the object but already with "json-updated" properties.

So to make things work I need to do this:?!

```
class RecordAuthorization(Authorization):
    def update_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        if User.objects.get(pk=bundle.obj.user.pk) == bundle.request.user:
            return True
        raise Unauthorized("You can't update this")
```

Answer (score 0):

For `update_list`, the `object_list` argument will be a queryset (or other iterable for non-Django ORM data sources) that should be filtered.

For `update_detail`, you want to check the properties of `bundle.obj`, which is an instance of your `Resource.Meta.object_class`, such as a Django model. If you set `Resource.Meta.queryset`, `Resource.Meta.object_class` is set for you.

There are indentation errors in your code, you should be raising Unauthorized at the method level, not the class level. If fixing that doesn't solve the issue, please post your resources.

Comment: I fixed now the indentation. I know that object_list will be a queryset and bundle.obj will be the Model instance (for me - Django ORM). The thing is that both the object_list and bundle.obj in update_list/detail contain data from the database AND from the current request => the fields specified in the API call will OVERWRITE the fields from the database. For me (and I think for some people, too) this is an unexpected behavior. Personally I though that there will be two data in these methods: The data from the database and The data from the api call (with missing fields database-supplemented)

Comment: But I am getting only the latter sort of data. Of course I can query the database myself, but as tastypie queries the database, too, I thought it would preserve also the original models from the database. Especially for the update_list function writting the query seems nontrivial as I need to extract the IDs from the queryset and run another query with those IDs.(if there's a simple function on the queryset to re-run it ,please, just tell me)

Comment: I see what you're saying. For now I'd just do another query. In the next release I'll add in the original object to the bundle. Here's the issue: https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/issues/1448